# Short VBA Script with Nested For Loops and If Statements Taking a While to Execute

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not a VBA expert - so bare with me on this one.

I have a spreadsheet of about 8000 rows, and I am trying to loop through all the rows in one column and compare it to one-two other sheets consisting of 45 and 85 rows respectively, if a value has not already been returned. It's basically comparing a date against a range of dates to see if it should be flagged.

Even with the `Exit For` statement when a date matches a range of dates and returns a value other than False or Null, the script is taking a long time to load. I understand that For Loops and If Statements can be pretty expensive for performance, but I'm not sure if there's another step I can take to speed up this performance?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Missing_CAT():

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim d As Date
Dim e As Date
Dim f As Date
Dim a As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowCount As Long

rowCount = Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To 3 'rowCount

    d = Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(i, 17).Value
    
    
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name = "2020" Or ws.Name = "2019" Then
            secondRowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
             For j = 5 To secondRowCount
                e = ws.Cells(j, 4).Value
                f = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value
                MsgBox (e & " " & f)
                If d >= e And d <= f Then
                    Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(i, 63).Value = ws.Cells(j, 6).Value
            a = ws.Cells(j,6).Value
            Exit For
               Else
                    Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(i, 63).Value = "FALSE"
               End If
            Next j
        Else
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        
    
NextIteration:
        Next
        
Next i

End Sub
```

Again - to try to alleviate my issue I added in an `Exit For` within the last nested If/For Loop so it would move on to the next row within the first sheet (8000 rows), but it's still taking a while.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: bulk load the values into variant arrays and loop those, put the output in another variant array and bulk load the range from that array.

Comment: Side note: get rid of the `Else` and `GoTo NextIteration`. They are not necessary, plus `GoTo` quickly leads to spaghetti code.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just want to make sure I understand this correctly - take the range of the column and set that as a Variant Array, loop over that array and load the results into another Variant Array, then load that Variant Array into the results column?

Comment: yup, something like: `firstArray = Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Range("Q2:Q" & rowCount).value`  Then make other arrays for the other data.  loop those.  Make a final array to hold the outputs that you assign to the range.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think this could work - but I can't figure out the "appending" to an Array. I have this:  
`If d >= e And d <= f Then
  ReDim Preserve resultArr(1 To UBound(resultArr) + 1)
 resultArr(UBound(resultArr), 1) = p
  Exit For `

Comment: make the output array the same size as the first input array, then you can skip the `ReDim Preserve`  Beyond that hint, if you are stuck ask a new question with your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Craner provided a good comment. Also, turn off `ScreenUpdating` and set `Calculation` to `xlManual` at the beginning of your code. At the end of your code turn `ScreenUpdating` on and set `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone down voted this, because this solved my issue. The previous comments were helpful, but they created many more issues. Thank you so much for this simple fix!